# Why $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{\alpha}}{1+n^2 x^2}$ doesn't converge uniformly on $[0, \infty)$ for $\alpha > 2$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, uniform-convergence

I'm trying to understand why $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^\alpha}{1+n^2 x^2}$ doesn't converge uniformly on $[0, \infty)$ for $\alpha > 2$.

My book says that $\frac{x^\alpha}{1+n^2 x^2}$ is monotonic and unbounded for $\alpha > 2$ therefore  it doesn't converge. I don't get why this means it can't converge exactly, someone care to explain?

Comment: Interesting! Just for fun, the series converges uniformly on $[0, \infty)$ if and only if $1 < \alpha \leq 2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because if a series of functions $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ converges uniformly, then the sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converge uniformly to the null function. So, the functions $f_n$ cannot be unbounded for every $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: If we fix $x \geq 0$, then for any $\alpha$, we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^{\alpha}}{1+n^2x^2} = 0$. So, this can't be right (unless I'm completely overlooking something)

Comment: @peek-a-boo My bad. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When $\alpha > 2$, then $\sup\frac{x^{\alpha}}{1+n^2 x^2} = +\infty$ so general member doesn't converged to $0$ uniformly.